# will java readLine() be able to read 1GB line

Tags: java, string, file-io, bufferedreader

BufferedReader#readLine() tries to fill its buffer with 8192 bytes. If the size of line itself is much greater than that will it throw an exception or read it in chunks and print the entire line?

Comment: 1 GB line? Is it like a super-long, minified CSS file, or what?

Comment: Why not try and debug it?

Comment: you should initialize your `BufferedReader` with the appropriate size

Comment: @jyoon 1GB CSS file? The corresponding website must look *really* good if its stylesheet is that large.

Comment: @Tom, it can also be a minified JS file. Still, amazing quality behind it.

Answer (score 7):

[`BufferedReader.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) is declared to return a `String` which can be 1 GB long. A `String` is a `char[]` in its internal representation, and the length of an array in Java can be much bigger than 10^9 (the max size of an array is a little less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

The implementation of `BufferedReader.readLine()` uses a [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) which also builds the `String` in a `char` array so that also doesn't prevent that the line to be 1GB long.

The internal buffer of `BufferedReader` does not limit the maximum line size, it is just used to speed up certain operations and to support the [`Reader.mark()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#mark-int-) and [`Reader.reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#reset--) operations.

**Note:**

It is in your favor that `String` stores characters not bytes, so the array limit applies to the number of characters which might be even more than the number of bytes depending on the character encoding used and the actual text content (for example if UTF-8 encoding is used, a character might even be encoded to 4 bytes of data).